# Spring - SOAP: "No endpoint mapping found for.."

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I have this problem:

```
 [L: org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound] - [M: No endpoint mapping found for 
 [SaajSoapMessage {http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service}getCountryRequest]]
```

following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) guide (no xml config).

My service config:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

@Bean(name = "countries")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {

    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {

    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
}
```

My endpoint:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

  private CountryRepository countryRepository;

  @Autowired
  public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
    this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
  }

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
  @ResponsePayload
  public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {

    GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
    response.setCountry(this.countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));

    return response;
  }
}
```

and the xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="country">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="currency">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

One note, I changed the import for service config because I'm on Spring 1.3.3, instead the guide it's on Spring 1.4 and more, so my import:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
```

it's deprecated.

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: your xsd is a simple schema file which describes an XML structure. It is not a valid WSDL which is the basic for soap.

Comment: I'm following the spring documentation for this!